# How to make my blazor web assembly list update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor-webassembly

I have an MVC project with blazor web assembly razor components embedded in the mvc cshtml pages.

One razor component contains the following items:

```
  @foreach (Thing thing in things)
  {
    <div>@(thing.Name)</div>
  }

 <EditForm Model="@(things)">
    <button type="button" @onclick="@(GetThings)">Get Things</button>
 </EditForm>

@code
{
     [Parameter]
     public AllThings allthings{ get; set; }

     private List<Thing> things{ get; set; }

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
          things= allthings.Things;
     }

     public async void GetThings()
     {
          IMyHttpClient myhttpclient = new MyHttpClient();
          List<Thing> newthings = await client.GoGetStuff("things/new");

          things = newthings;
     }
 }
```

The service, `MyHttpClient`, is returning a new list okay but the rendered list on the page just disappears.
I have tried iterating through the initial `things` list in the `GetThings` method and just deleting a few items then adding items from the `newthings` list, the old items disappear but the new items do not render.
How can I get the list to update please?

Comment: Thank you, @Henk Holterman. I added a field and variable to display the count of list items from the new list and it is correct.
The problem is the new items are not being bound to the list.

Comment: Spot on, @Henk Holterman. Thank you.
I couldn't imagine the returned list being the correct count every time withough the data.
The API controller returns the correct list according to the breakpoints and postman.
The http client class I use is tried and tested in xamarin forms apps.
I have no idea why the name property is empty.
I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
public async Task GetThings()
```

instead of

```
public async void GetThings()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, @Surinder Singh.
Unfortunately, the list is still just going blank.

Comment: But do keep it an `async Task`, you don't need async void here.

Comment: Please try using StateHasChanged(); as last line in method GetThings()